# Confluence REST API authorization

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, confluence

1. User already logged in Confluence;
2. There is another external WEB application which saves attachments to the concrete page.
3. To perform rest calls from an external app I need to know user and password of confluence user (but I don't know it because authorization already was passed. Or it is possible using session id;

How to get access token for REST access? How perform ajax call using access confluence token?

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost:1990/confluence/rest/api/content",
  headers: "Basic=" + GET_SOMEHOW_ACCESS_TOKEN,
  success: function(html){
      console.log(html)
  }
 });
```

Comment: you can use do using curl  for get,post,put and delete
curl -u "user":"pass" -L "https://yourdomain.atlassian.net/wiki/rest/api/content/{id}

Answer (score 0):

You want to impersonate a user and perform an operation on their behalf, without authentication. In general, you cannot do that. It's a form of Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF), although for benign purposes. Applications should be protected against those.

Comment: Yes, but user can create JIRA tickets from the confluence. It means that Confluence can cooperate somehow with Other apps? The other example is Gliffy diagrams. We can save diagram in gliffy and it will be saved in confluence attachments.

Answer (score 0):

I investigated a bit and it appears that you can actually impersonate a user through the API. I'm reporting [Martin Cassidy's answer on the Atlassian forum](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/How-do-you-impersonate-a-user-with-JIRA-oauth/qaq-p/476116), slightly edited to fix the spelling:

What you need to do is:

- Create a public and private key pair
- Setup the trusted application using the Jira GUI, enabling the 2 legged OAuth option
- Send requests as you normally would (forget about request tokens and access and access tokens, and include the following parameters in the query string of your request

  - oauth_consumer_key - the name of your consumer as set in the trusted application setup through the Jira GUI
  - oauth_token - an empty string
  - oauth_signature_method - should be RSA-SHA1 as this is all Jira supports
  - oauth_signature - the signature for your request, you'll have to generate this using your private key. If using Java, I recommend the net.oauth classes, same as in the Jira OAuth example (https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA%2520REST%2520API%2520Example%2520-%2520OAuth%2520authentication)
  - oauth_timestamp - Again, you can generate this automatically with net.oauth
  - oauth_nonce - again, generate automatically as above
  - user_id - optional, if specified, Jira will run the RESTful request as the specified user. If not given, Jira will run the request using the user you specified in the Execute as of the trusted application configuration.

Note that Martin is talking about a Java client using Jersey. You can do the same in JavaScript, but you should be aware that you'll be leaking the private access token to Confluence, allowing anyone who grabs it to make requests on behalf of your application. So, it is advisable to implement that part server-side, where you can hide the API key from prying eyes.